# Jenkins do not run test through GitHub hooks

Tags: github, jenkins

I have Jenkins job configuration where I have a Trigger phrase set to: `.*jenkins:\W+run\W+tests\W+sanity.*` and I have PR from this repo where I'm adding comment `jenkins: run tests sanity` and nothing is happening. I do not know what is missing. I was actually copied all configuration from the job which also operating on GH hooks. Any ideas what else I should check?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to run this finally.
You need to set both of these options to `true`:

- *Only use trigger phrase for build triggering*
- *Build every pull request automatically without asking (Dangerous!)*

Now it is working when I run it manually from the PR, using *jenkins: run tests sanity*.